# how to use json_decode in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json

I requested data from Rest API and it's data was encoded before response to client. My response object is

```
{homes = "[{\"info\":{\"id\":\"001\",\"description\":\"\",\"posted_date\":\"2015-02-12 09:42:31\"}},{\"info\":{\"id\":\"002\",\"description\":\"test\",\"posted_date\":\"2015-02-12 09:42:31\"}}]";}
```

I want use Objective-c to decode or convert this object to this format:

```
{ 
   homes = (
       { info = { id = 001; "description":""; "posted_date" = "2015-02-12 09:42:31";}};
       { info = { id = 002; "description":"test"; "posted_date" = "2015-02-12 09:42:31";}};
      );
}
```

Please give me some idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do some basic searching. A quick search here or with Google will reveal an absurd number of resources for parsing JSON data in Objective-C.

Comment: and now absurd_number += 3

Answer (score 0):

You should use method like `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];`

`data` parameter is `NSData` object that can be evaluated by calling `[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by using

SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *tmpHome = [jsonParser objectWithString:[JSON valueForKey:@"homes"] error:nil];

Thanks so much for all nice idea :)